# (see screenshot) What is the significance of this random variable?

Tags: probability, statistics

[image: statistics]

This section of the textbook is summarizing the important properties of least squares estimators. All is well until they reach the seventh property - in the main text, this random variable was mentioned without any context. What does it mean, and why should I care about its distribution (as opposed to the distribution of SSE itself)?

Comment: This distribution shows up in other contexts, so knowing about it is useful in general.  In this case, it tells you something about the random variation in $S^2$: its fluctuations are modelable by  those of a chi-squared r.v., at least when the gaussian error model is correct.

Comment: "as opposed to the distribution of SSE itself" - But this in fact gives you the distribution of SSE.

Comment: @StubbornAtom if that's true, then why didn't the authors simply specify the distribution of $(n-2)*S^2$? What is the significance of including the denominator?

Comment: Because (in other words) distribution of $SSE$ is $\sigma^2$ times a $\chi^2_{n-2}$ distribution. The denominator hasn't been added separately; the entire thing is what you will end up with while deriving the distribution.